# nginx Bad Gateway after changing port for GitLab

Tags: nginx, debian, gitlab

I have GitLab installed and running fine on the default port `80` so I know my installation works. The problem is when I try to change the port to `8080` I get a "502 Bad Gateway" error.

I replaced `port: 80` with `port: 8080` in my `gitlab.yml`.

I also replaced `listen *:80 default_server;` with `listen *:8080 default_server;` in my `nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab`

My `gitlab_error.log` shows the following (I've removed my IP and server name from the log entry.)

```
2013/11/09 10:51:02 [crit] 2648#0: *1 connect() to unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: *******, server: ********, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket:/", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080"
```

Everything works fine when on port `80` but not on `8080`.

What step(s) I am missing?

Comment: please share the nginx config file

Answer (score 3):

Unicorn is also using port 8080 by default so you have a conflict.